# How to login + ask permissions only *once* [Facebook] [Android]

Tags: android, facebook, permissions, facebook-login

I'm having a bit of problem with the Facebook API (3.0). I read *a lot* of questions regarding this matter before coming here to ask my own. Most people settle for "just ask separately for read/write permissions" but I do not want that at all.

I would like to - not using the facebookLoginButton - login and *at the sime time* ask for permission (*publish_stream*). I know this is possible because several apps do it, like Instagram for example.

Can anyone please show me how? I've been trying to find this information for a while but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Which permissions? Read or publish?

Comment: I'd like to ask aditional permissions - for now publish_stream.

Comment: I suspect you may need to downgrade your SDK for that; `Note: In the new SDK (3.0), you may ask only for read permissions when you first open a session. You should not prompt your user for publish permissions until the time at which they are actually publishing an action to Facebook. `.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Right, but why can other apps do it? Like mentioned Instagram does it, but there are others out there...

Comment: Do they actually use the 3.0 SDK or an earlier version that didn't have that restriction?

Comment: Please DO NOT downgrade and use an older version. Functionality on older versions of the SDK are NOT guaranteed to work into the future. There's a reason why the 3.0 SDK requires you to separate read and publish permissions, and if you use 2.0 instead, there's no guarantee that your app will work at a later date. You should instead design your app to fit with the new Facebook API.

Comment: @MingLi i have a problem when i login with facebook from my app...a screen appears samsung galaxy asking for facebook permission..and if i denied my app crashes??can you please help

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with the SDK, I think it's specific to Samsung phones, and is something the manufacturer is injecting, not sure how to get around it other than to authorize the samsung app.